# How to make Exceptions in getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, php

I am using getElementsByTagName in PHP to select all the image with img tag in the DOM.

Actually, I am using it for Lazy loading images. With PHP and JS it is working perfectly but I want neglect first image with img tag and choose all other img tags.

is there anyway I can make exceptions for the first img tag. 
Here is the code I am using to select all img tags.

```
$imgs = $post->getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Comment: Please add your entire code which is giving you this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know your code structure but you should 
but commonly if like this 
you can do

**$imgs = $post->getElementsByTagName('div > img:not(:first-child)');**

```
<body>
<div>
   <img>
   <img>
   <img>
   <img>
   <img>
</div>
</body>
```